# MeteorJs Error makes the site stop loading

Tags: node.js, meteor

```
Eror: url must be a relative URL: http://www.mafengwo.com/
    at _.extend.classify (packages/routepolicy/routepolicy.js:103)
    at Object.Inject.appUrl (packages/meteorhacks:inject-initial/lib/inject-core.js:43)
    at Object.Package [as handle] (packages/gadicohen:headers/headers-server.js:192)
    at next (/home/timekeeper/bundle/programs/server/npm/webapp/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at next (/home/timekeeper/bundle/programs/server/npm/webapp/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:165:78)
    at Function.app.handle (/home/timekeeper/bundle/programs/server/npm/webapp/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:198:3)
    at Object.fn [as handle] (/home/timekeeper/bundle/programs/server/npm/webapp/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:74:14)
    at next (/home/timekeeper/bundle/programs/server/npm/webapp/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
    at Object.WebAppInternals.staticFilesMiddleware (packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:400)
    at packages/webapp/webapp_server.js:651
```

I get the above error and i have no idea what it means . I don't even know where the url comes from. But it makes my website work no more.

Comment: How are we supposed to help without any code?

Comment: Consider updating your question with relevant code samples and describe what leads to the error message (eg. what changes lead to the error message)

Comment: This is not because of any code. It's a problem with the framework itself. Since some bot is trying to access the site illegally which is causing this issue

Comment: Seems to be like a known issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1212. A bot is trying to access your site. It seems that this shouldn't be of nay concern.